# Plot Overlap Class in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have a data frame of 3 classes (Class1, Class2, and Class3)
Now I need the plot class in an overlapping manner, as shown in the below figure

```
import pandas as pd
df = [[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,1]]
column_names=["Class1","Class2","Class3"]
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=column_names)
print(df)
```

Expected Output
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Plotting a Venn diagram programatically is surprisingly hard in Python, or in general. R's [Vennerable](https://github.com/js229/Vennerable) seems to be the best, and in Python the best is [matplotlib-venn](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn). This allows you to create a Venn diagram based on the sets, which you can do based on index. Note that:

- This doesn't look great because there are some sets with no unique values in your example.
- This plots counts of intersection/union/difference, and can be modified to show percentage instead, but doesn't plot the actual set members.
- This also won't work with more than 3 columns.

Code:

```
# pip install matplotlib-venn

from matplotlib_venn import venn3

subsets = [set(df.loc[df[col]==1].index) for col in df.columns]

venn3(subsets, set_labels =df.columns)
```

[image]